# In how many ways can we select $5$ dancers if those $5$ dancers have to be from at least $4$ of the five $15$ member dance teams?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem:

Their are $5$ dance teams which have sent $15$ of their dancers (each team has $15$ dancers, total of $75$ dancers) to a competition.  In how many ways can we select $5$ dancers if those $5$ dancers have to be from **at least** 4 teams?

(at least $4$ teams means that there can be $4$ teams or $5$ teams - which obviously involves addition of two combinations)

Can I tackle the problem with combinations since the order does not matter (factorials are not involved)?

[image]

I' m sure I did a pretty bad mistake here... Help is appreciated.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig: You may as well change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that there are two possibilities:

1. The five dancers are selected from five different teams.
2. The five dancers are selected from four different teams, with two dancers belonging to the same team.

If the five dancers are chosen from five different teams, then there are fifteen ways to choose each dancer.  Thus, the number of possible selections is $15^5$.

If the five dancers are chosen from four teams, then two dancers must be selected from one team.  This team can be selected in $5$ ways.   The number of ways of selecting two of the fifteen dancers on that team is $\binom{15}{2}$.  The remaining three dancers must be selected from three of the four remaining teams, which can be selected in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways.  There are $15$ ways to choose one dancer from each of those teams.  Hence, the number of ways the dancers can be selected from four separate teams is 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{15}{1}^3$$

In total, the number of ways of selecting the dancers is 
$$\binom{15}{1}^5 + \binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{15}{1}^3$$

Comment: Very good explanation... of the givern solution. Everything just fits perfectly. I was tackling the problem too fast instead of analyzing tings/elements like you did. Tnx!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.